# PHP array_slice increment when used in foreach

Tags: php, foreach, slice

I am trying to use `array_slice` to loop through JSON objects and then to create another JSON from it. But for some reason, every loop increment the previous object.
For example, if I have this JSON

```
{
  "message":[
     {"id":1},
     {"id":2}
  ]
}
```

and I use  `array_slice` to loop through and print the id key, the result will be

```
id 1
id 1, id 2
```

and I want it to be

```
id 1
id 2
```

**This is what I have as a code**

```
$result = '{"message":[{"id":1},{"id":2}]}';

$array = json_decode($result, true);
$json_response = array();

foreach (array_slice($array['message'], 0, 10) as $slot) {
    $row_array['buttons'][] = array(
            'caption' => $slot['id'],
            );
    array_push($json_response, $row_array);
}

$final_json = [
        "elements" => $json_response
    ];
```

**And here is a working demo**

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/38fa1b406e4c845cd8d56155d72e4d2b86b3b2cb)

**The expected result would be**

```
{
    "elements": [
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "caption": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "caption": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please add an example of what _result_ you actually want to get here? I can’t currently see what _point_ slicing is supposed to have here.

Comment: The point of slicing is that I want to limit the result if I have for example 20 ids I want to show only 10

Comment: You don't need the `[]` in `$row_array['buttons'][] = ` as this will keep on adding the values to the list.  Not sure if just removing this would work for you.

Comment: Do you want multiple `buttons` keys or just one?

Comment: @NigelRen, The buttons must be array of objects, so [] is a must I guess.

Comment: In php, variables can live after a loop, meaning, that $row_array is still alive after the first iteration, and have in it the value that already been added. just add array initialization for $row_array['buttons'] or instead of adding the value into an array, just assign the value

Comment: @AbraCadaver just added the expected result example in the description

Comment: But you set it to `array(...)`, so that gives the array.

Comment: just add     $row_array['buttons'] = [];
before $row_array['buttons'][] = array(...

Comment: @NigelRen, the problem is that inclement the values not that it is an array. The second object should contain only id 2, not id 1 and id 2

Comment: @vladkatz, you are absolutely right. Can you please, write it as an answer, so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @NigelRen answer is a better one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php, variables can live after a loop, meaning, that $row_array is still alive after the first iteration, and have in it the value that already been added. just add array initialization for $row_array['buttons'] or instead of adding the value into an array, just assign the value.

first solution:

```
foreach (array_slice($array['message'], 0, 10) as $slot) {
    $row_array['buttons'] = [];
    $row_array['buttons'][] = array('caption' => $slot['id'],);
    array_push($json_response, $row_array);
}
```

second solution:

```
foreach (array_slice($array['message'], 0, 10) as $slot) {
    $row_array['buttons'] = [array('caption' => $slot['id'],)];
    array_push($json_response, $row_array);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That did it!

Answer (score 2):

When you are adding the items in...

```
$row_array['buttons'][]
```

The `[]` is just adding the new item to an existing value (i.e. all of the other values you have added so far).  Also as you have `= array()` this gives the array you need.  So remove the `[]`...

```
 $row_array['buttons'] =  [['caption' => $slot['id']]];
```

The extra set of `[]`'s around the value gives the extra level of nesting required.

This is your sandbox gives...

```
{
    "elements": [
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "caption": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "caption": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Almost there. The burrons should be `"buttons": [{"caption": 1 }]`

Comment: vlad katz, already gave the correct answer - adding `$row_array['buttons'] = [];` before `$row_array['buttons'][] = array(...` did the trick